# How to write the Python/Pandas equivalent of the following R code?

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

For a project, I am attempting to convert the following R code to Python but I am struggling to write equivalent code for the summarize and mutate commands used in R. The code :

```
  users <- users %>% 
  mutate(coup_start=ifelse(first_coup>DAY,"no","yes")) %>%
  group_by(household_key,WEEK_NO,coup_start) %>% 
  summarize(weekly_spend=sum(SALES_VALUE),
            dummy=1) #adding new column dummy

users_before <- filter(users,coup_start=="no")
users_after <- filter(users,coup_start=="yes")

users_before <- users_before %>%
  group_by(household_key) %>%
  mutate(cum_dummy=cumsum(dummy),
         trip=cum_dummy-max(cum_dummy)) %>%
  select(-dummy,-cum_dummy)

users_after <- users_after %>%
  group_by(household_key) %>%
  mutate(trip=cumsum(dummy)-1) %>%
  select(-dummy)
```

I tried the following :

```
users = transaction_data.merge(coupon_users,on='household_key')
users['coup_start']=  np.where((users['first_coup'] > users['DAY_x']), 1, 0)
users['dummy'] = 1

users_before = users[users['coup_start']==0]
users_after = users[users['coup_start']==1]

users_before['cum_dummy'] = users_before.groupby(['household_key'])['dummy'].cumsum()
users_before['trip'] = users_before.groupby(['household_key'])['cum_dummy'].transform(lambda x: x - x.max())

users_after['trip'] = users_after.groupby(['household_key'])['dummy'].transform(lambda x: cumsum(x) - 1)
```

But I'm encountering multiple issues, the transform(lambda x: cumsum(x) -1) is throwing an error. And the two groupby and transform attempts before that show the following warnings:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
"""Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.

I also feel that I did not insert the dummy = 1 correctly initially. How can I convert the mutate/summarize functions in R with Python?

### Edit

I have attempted using apply function to perform the cumsum operation.

```
def thisop(x): return(cumsum(x)-1 )
users_after['trip']=users_after.groupby(['household_key'])['dummy'].apply(thisop)
```

The error : `NameError: name 'cumsum' is not defined` still persists.

Comment: Please add sample data and expected output in text.

Comment: You need "x.cumsum()" instead of "cumsum(x)" since it's a pd.DataFrame method.

Answer (score 0):

You've changed some variable and value names from R to Python code (e.g.`DAY` to `DAY_X`).
The following code should work taking the variables/values from your R code:

```
users = (
    users.assign(coup_start = np.where(users.first_coup > users.DAY), 'no', 'yes')
    .groupby(['household_key','WEEK_NO','coup_start'])
    .agg(weekly_spend=(SALES_VALUE, sum))
    .assign(dummy=1)
)

users_before = users.query('coup_start=="no"')
users_after = users.query('coup_start=="yes"')

users_before = (
    users_before.assign (
        trip = users_before.groupby('household_key').dummy
        .transform(lambda x: x.cumsum() - x.cumsum().max()) )
    .drop(columns='dummy')
)

users_after = (
    users_after.assign (
        trip = users_after.groupby('household_key')
        .transform(trip = dummy.cumsum()-1) )
    .drop(columns='dummy')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using the same syntax in python:

```py
from datar.all import f, mutate, if_else, summarize, filter, group_by, select, sum, cumsum, max

users = users >> \
  mutate(coup_start=if_else(f.first_coup>f.DAY,"no","yes")) >> \
  group_by(f.household_key,f.WEEK_NO,f.coup_start) >> \
  summarize(weekly_spend=sum(f.SALES_VALUE),
            dummy=1) #adding new column dummy

users_before = filter(users,f.coup_start=="no")
users_after = filter(users,f.coup_start=="yes")

users_before = users_before >> \
  group_by(f.household_key) >> \
  mutate(cum_dummy=cumsum(f.dummy),
         trip=f.cum_dummy-max(f.cum_dummy)) >> \
  select(~f.dummy,~f.cum_dummy)

users_after = users_after >> \
  group_by(f.household_key) >> \
  mutate(trip=cumsum(f.dummy)-1) >> \
  select(~f.dummy)
```

I am the author of the [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) package. Feel free to submit issues if you have any questions.